# Compact radial Sobolev embedding $H^1_{rad}\hookrightarrow L^p$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I want to show:
Let $N\geq 2$ and $2< q <2^\ast$. Then the embedding \begin{align}
H^1_{\text{rad}}(\mathbb{R}^N)\hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb{R}^N)
\end{align}
is compact.

I was able to show that \begin{align}|u(r)|\leq C R^{\frac{-(N-1)}{2}} \|\nabla u\|_2^{\frac{1}{2}} \|u\|_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \hat C R^{\frac{-(N-1)}{2}} \|u\|_{H^1} \end{align} holds almost everywhere for $r\geq R$.

How can I conclude now? I think the idea would be to use the above estimate to be able to only restrict on a bounded domain and then use the usual Rellich-Kondrachov embedding. But how to make this rigorous? Do I need some cut-off?

I also posted the question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157769/compactness-sobolev-embedding-for-radial-functions-on-mathbbrn) but received no answers.

I would also be happy about any reference regarding this proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Strauss embedding theorem for radially symmetric functions, proven here:

W. A. Strauss, *Existence of solitary waves in higher dimensions*, Commun. Math.
Phys. 55 (1977), 149-162.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid but let $q=2+\epsilon$ then $|x|^{-q\frac{N-1}{2}} = |x|^{-(N-1)} |x|^{-\epsilon \frac{N-1}{2}}$. Then I think this is only integrable if $\epsilon \frac{N-1}{2} >1$.

Comment: Uhm... I got it mentally and I was sure it was. I'll remove the suggestion then.

Comment: Thanks anyway, an answer has been posted on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157769/compactness-sobolev-embedding-for-radial-functions-on-mathbbrn/1159319#1159319